# Can I alter exceptions before Elmah logs them?

Tags: elmah

I'm using Elmah in a WebForms app and would like the ability to alter an exception before Elmah logs it. In my scenario there are exceptions being thrown by some of my dependency components that have many custom InnerExceptions with details that Elmah ignores. So I'd like the opportunity to iterate the InnerExceptions and add textual details to the main exception just before Elmah logs it.

I can see how I would filter exceptions entirely, but it doesn't look like I could alter the exception and still allow it to be logged. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you handle your exceptions instead of leaving them unhandled for ELMAH to pick up automatically, and raise a custom exception with some property that ELMAH reads overridden to display what you want from your custom exception properties? e.g. Message

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

We addressed this by forking Elmah locally and adding code to iterate over the exceptions as per the suggestions in this Elmah issue:

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=162&can=1&q=data

Building our own version also allowed us to add a couple of other things that the current version of Elmah doesn't provide out of the box.

---

As an aside the next version of Elmah is in development - there seem to be substantial changes to a least some of the codebase - so I'll need to revisit this problem and our other additional logging requirements once it gets to release.